# Materialized View Does Not Appear In Geometry_Columns View

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have defined a materialized view in a PostGIS 2.1-enabled database running PostgreSQL 9.3.1:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW canvec_data.contours_m AS 
 SELECT
    contours_original.ogc_fid, 
    contours_original.elevation::integer AS elevation_orig, 
    CASE
        WHEN "substring"(contours_original.code::text, 1, 3) = '257'::text THEN round(contours_original.elevation::double precision * 0.3048::double precision)
        ELSE contours_original.elevation::double precision
    END AS elevation_m, 
    contours_original.wkb_geometry::geometry(Linestring,3578)
 FROM canvec_data.contours_original
```

I had, perhaps erroneously, expected that this resultant entity (a table?) would be listed in the `public.geometry_columns` view, and thus be properly interpreted by GIS viewer software such as QGIS.

The materialized view does not appear in the `public.geometry_columns` view.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, you discovered a hole in our support for PostgreSQL 9.3's new materialized view feature. I've patched all the relevant branches, and you can update your definition of geometry_columns yourself (see the change references in this ticket http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2511)

Actually, here's something you can just paste into the SQL window:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW geometry_columns AS 
  SELECT current_database()::varchar(256) AS f_table_catalog, 
    n.nspname::varchar(256) AS f_table_schema, 
    c.relname::varchar(256) AS f_table_name, 
    a.attname::varchar(256) AS f_geometry_column, 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(postgis_typmod_dims(a.atttypmod),2),
             postgis_constraint_dims(n.nspname, c.relname, a.attname),
             2) AS coord_dimension, 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(postgis_typmod_srid(a.atttypmod),0),
             postgis_constraint_srid(n.nspname, c.relname, a.attname),
             0) AS srid, 
    -- force to be uppercase with no ZM so is backwards compatible
    -- with old geometry_columns
    replace(
      replace(
        COALESCE(
          NULLIF(upper(postgis_typmod_type(a.atttypmod)::text), 'GEOMETRY'),
          postgis_constraint_type(n.nspname, c.relname, a.attname),
          'GEOMETRY'
        ), 'ZM', ''
      ), 'Z', ''
    )::varchar(30) AS type
  FROM pg_class c, pg_attribute a, pg_type t, pg_namespace n
  WHERE t.typname = 'geometry'::name 
    AND a.attisdropped = false 
    AND a.atttypid = t.oid 
    AND a.attrelid = c.oid 
    AND c.relnamespace = n.oid 
    AND (c.relkind = 'r'::"char" OR c.relkind = 'v'::"char" OR c.relkind = 'm'::"char")
    AND NOT pg_is_other_temp_schema(c.relnamespace)
    AND NOT ( n.nspname = 'public' AND c.relname = 'raster_columns' )
    AND has_table_privilege( c.oid, 'SELECT'::text );
```

Comment: Great reply and fix; that is customer service...